# modify html elements in woocommerce plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i'm working with woocommerce plugin in wordpress and i want modify the search bar (styles and html) the php that contains is thaps-search-from.php in the image you can see the directory route,

[image: https://i.imgur.com/rTBTF3W.png]

for example I want delete the button

```
 <button id='thaps-search-button' value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Submit','submit button', 'th-advance-product-search' ); ?>" type='submit'>
```

modify the file directly and this worked but

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all that is not the WooCommerce plugin that you're working on. it's [TH Advance Product Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/th-advance-product-search/) plugin for advanced product search.

This plugin doesn't have template path-based customization but it provides a filter that you can use to customize the form HTML file.

In file https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/th-advance-product-search/trunk/inc/thaps.php you can find this line, that gives you a hook to provide a file path, which means you can copy the file into your child theme and add a filter on this hook and return your child theme file path.

```php
$filename = apply_filters( 'thaps_form_path', TH_ADVANCE_PRODUCT_SEARCH_PLUGIN_PATH . '/inc/thaps-search-from.php' );
```

First of all copy `inc/thaps-search-from.php` file in your child theme's `woocommerce` folder, and you can make customization in this copied file.

then you need to add this code to replace the file path.

```php
/**
 * Modify form file path.
 */
add_filter(
    'thaps_form_path',
    function() {
        // return the file complete path from the woocommerce directory in which we copied the file.
        return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/thaps-search-from.php'
    }
);
```

**Note: I have not tested the code so if you find any error after adding the code, please let me know what is the error I will fix the code.**

Answer (score 0):

i think you ll need to copy that file to your theme folder under woocommerce folder to override it and modify it, in other words you have to create a folder called woocommerce and put that specific folder/file to it, like that if woocommerce get updated it ll not break/reset your code.